# $\gamma<\theta$ iff $\gamma\in\theta$

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I'm struggling with my homework:

Let $\gamma,\theta$ be order types. Then, $\gamma<\theta$ iff $\gamma\in\theta$.

I already proved that if $\gamma\in\theta$, then $\gamma<\theta$. To do the other implication, I thought of using contradiction and proceeding by trichotomy, but I don't see what to do next. :/

Comment: This depends on your definitions and axioms a bit: How specifically have you defined an order type and how is $\gamma < \theta$ defined?

Comment: @AndrewL $\langle\gamma,\in\rangle\lessapprox\langle\theta,\in\rangle$ iff $\gamma<\beta$

Comment: Ordinals are transitive sets: Let $g,t\in On$ and $g\in t.$ Then $g\subseteq t.$ And the well-order $\in$ on $t$ is irreflexive so $g\in t\implies (\neg (g\in g))\implies g\ne t $ (regardless of Foundation/Regularity). So $g$ is an initial segment of $t.$ The well-order $\in$ on $t $ cannot be isomorphic to an initial segment of itself:  Suppose $f:t\to g$ is a bijection. Then since $g\subsetneqq t,$ there exists $x=\min_{\in} \{y\in t:f(y)\ne y\}.$ Let $z=f^{-1}(x).$ Then  $x\in z$ and $f(z)=x\in  f(x)$ so $f$ does not preserve the strict linear $\in$-order.